# javascript - jquery ui: calling .droppable on non-existing div doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a code like this one:

```
$('div.widgetDroppable').droppable({
    accept: 'li.widget',
 drop: function(event, ui) { 
     self.dropEventHandler(event, ui, $(this));
 }
});
```

I allow the user to add many of those widgetDroppable divs dinamically (through a code like `$('#page').append(SOME_HTML_CODE)`): the problem (which isn't a real problem actually, but I don't like it this way) is that if I put the previous code before any of the widgetDroppable divs has been created it won't work, it seems like it doesn't bind the 'droppable' thing to the divs because there's no one of them at the moment. I had to put that code inside a method which is called anytime the user adds a div, but I'd like to avoid that. Is this possible?

Also, I don't understand if this is a default behaviour in jQuery because I noticed that for other kind of divs the code is working anyway apparently even if they have not been created yet.

Comment: SOLUTION:
Since .live() doesn't support only callbacks as argument I created a custom event called 'divAdded' which gets triggered using .trigger() every time that a div.widgetDroppable is created. Then I used the first piece of code as a call back to .live('divAdded', callback) and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably solve this by using [livequery](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs).

Your code would look something like this:

```
$('div.widgetDroppable').livequery(function(){
    $(this).droppable({
        accept: 'li.widget',
        drop: function(event, ui) { 
            self.dropEventHandler(event, ui, $(this));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: There is already a .live() function inside jQuery. Is this any different from the livequery plugin? Also, I know this is related to binding events to DOM elements which have not been created yet, but .droppable() is not an event so I shouldn't be able to use this anyway. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I believe that live() currently doesn't support only callbacks as argument without binding one of the events supported by jQuery. With the example above, every time a div with the class 'widgetDroppable' is created, the callback will be executed in the scope of this newly created element. Which should also answer your second question regarding the events. With "livequery" you do not need to bind an event.

Comment: I commented before you added the example code. You're right that live() doesn't support callbacks without binding an event at the moment, so this seems to be my only solution. Thanks

Comment: Well, I didn't actually solved by using your answer but I'll accept it because the solution came to my mind just thanks to it. I've posted my solution in a comment to my answer in case anyone is interested.